# regular expression for name in net

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hello I've got a problem with regular expression for Name

Here are  my requirements:

1. To start with character - a-z - one or more
2. Then it can have white space or hyphen
3. it must end with character a-z

here is what I wrote but it doesn't work

```
[a-zA-Z]+$/-*/s*";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
^            # start-of-string
[a-z]+       # one ore more characters at the start
[ -]         # match a space or a hyphen
[a-z]        # match a character at the end
$            # match the end-of-string
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work -

`^(?i)[a-z]+[\ -].*[a-z]$`

```
 ^               # Beginning of string
 (?i)            # Case insensitive modifier group
 [a-z]+          # 1 or more a-z or A-Z
 [\ -]           # Space or -
 .*              # 0 or more any character
 [a-z]           # 1 a-z or A-Z
 $               # End of string
```